# XDocument Load to ToList

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am Loading .xml file with help of XDocument. I succesfully read .xml file.

C# code:

```
XDocument doci = XDocument.Load(path);
var mijav = from r in doci.Descendants("Configuration").Descendants("DayRoutine").Descendants("DayRoutine").Where(r => (int)r.Attribute("ID") == 4)
            select new
            {
                Button = r.Element("Button").Value,
                DataPoints = r.Elements("DayRoutinePoints").Select(c => (string)c.Value).ToList(),
            };
```

Problem I have is in DataPoint variable. I get only one value in "one" array and all the points are writen in this array. How to divide this data for every readed line?

DataPoint variable now:

```
"00:00:00, 44004:45:00, 48013:35:00, 60015:00:00, 41519:55:00, 600"
```

Points data in XML and how I like to have:

```
"00:00:00, 440
 04:45:00, 480
 13:35:00, 600
 15:00:00, 415
 19:55:00, 600"
```

My XML file:

```
<blabla>
   <Infos>
      <ConfigurationName>XXConfigurationName</ConfigurationName>
     <DateSaved>14.10.2015 13:14:01</DateSaved>
   </Infos>
 <Configuration>
    <DayRoutine>
       <DayRoutine ID="4">
          <Button>1</Button>
          <SetupOption>StaticBasic_DoffEoff</SetupOption>
          <DayRoutinePoints>
             <Point0>00:00:00, 440</Point0>
             <Point1>04:45:00, 480</Point1>
             <Point2>13:35:00, 600</Point2>
             <Point3>15:00:00, 415</Point3>
             <Point4>19:55:00, 600</Point4>
          </DayRoutinePoints>
       </DayRoutine>
   </DayRoutine>
  </Configuration>
</blabla>
```

Comment: Are there always 5 points numbered 0-4?

Comment: In this case yes it is always 5 points

Comment: you need to select the elements of DayRoutinePoints and have all of them in 1 string, you can separate them using `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
XDocument doci = XDocument.Load(path);
        var mijav =
            doci.Descendants("Configuration")
                .Descendants("DayRoutine")
                .Descendants("DayRoutine")
                .Where(r => (int) r.Attribute("ID") == 4)
                .Select(r => new
                {
                    Button = r.Element("Button").Value,
                    DataPoints =
                        r.Elements("DayRoutinePoints").Elements()
                            .Select(c => (string) c.Value)
                            .ToList(),
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
DataPoints = String.Join(" ", r.Elements("DayRoutinePoints")
.Elements()
.Select(x=>x.Value.ToString()+Environment.NewLine))
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are selecting all `DayRoutinePoints` elements of `DayRoutine` and that gives you single element. Then you are reading its value which is values of all nested point elements. That's why you have array with single value.

All you need to do - select single `DayRoutinePoints` element and get it's child elements:

```
DataPoints = r.Element("DayRoutinePoints").Elements().Select(c => (string)c).ToList(),
```

NOTE: With XPath your parsing can look more simple (I omitted also converting points to list)

```
from r in doci.XPathSelectElements("//Configuration/DayRoutine/DayRoutine[@ID=4]")    
select new
{
    Button = (string)r.Element("Button"),
    DataPoints = from p in r.Element("DayRoutinePoints").Elements()
                 select (string)p
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the selection problem, you need to select all of the descendants of the node `<DayRoutinePoints>` and fetch their values.

```
DataPoints = r.Descendants("DayRoutinePoints")
              .Descendants().Select(c => (string)c.Value).ToList(),
```

The original code was essentially taking the inner text of the `DayRoutinePoints` node, which ends up being the content of the node with all the XML stripped out.